# Why is safari's element width considerably differently as reported from chrome and firefox, when using a custom font-family?

Tags: javascript, css, safari, width, font-face

These are the results of Javascript's offsetWidth:

Chrome WITHOUT custom font-family:
Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_12_6) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/60.0.3112.90 Safari/537.36

> element offsetWidth = 393

Firefox WITHOUT custom font-family:
Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.12; rv:54.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/54.0

> element offsetWidth = 393

Safari WITHOUT custom font-family:
Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_12_6) AppleWebKit/603.3.8 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/10.1.2 Safari/603.3.8

> element offsetWidth = 394

Now, when uncommenting the custom font-family for -tag in styles.css:

Chrome WITH custom font-family:
Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_12_6) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/60.0.3112.90 Safari/537.36

> element offsetWidth = 416

Firefox WITH custom font-family:
Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.12; rv:54.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/54.0

> element offsetWidth = 416

Safari WITH custom font-family:
Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_12_6) AppleWebKit/603.3.8 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/10.1.2 Safari/603.3.8

> element offsetWidth = 1047

What? **element offsetWidth = 1047?** Why? What's wrong?
What's wrong with the code, or is it a bug in safari?

I think, this (wrong?) behavior of safari will have an impact for the following css-animation, where the percent x-position in @keyframes will depend on the elements width.

By the way, Safari breaks the animated text with custom font-family arbitrary!!!

I hope, someone has an explanation for me, thanks in advance :-)

Here are the code-files

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>

<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0">

<title>Element Width</title>

<!-- loading from google fonts -->
<!-- font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif; -->
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans" rel="stylesheet">

<!-- loading with google's webfont loader -->
<!--
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/webfont/1.6.26/webfont.js"></script>
<script>
    WebFont.load({
        google: {
            families: ['Open+Sans']
        }
    });
</script>
-->

<!-- font-face -->
<!-- <link rel="stylesheet" href="font/open_sans/styles.css"> -->

<!-- default styles -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css">

<!-- animation styles -->
<!-- <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/animate.css"> -->

</head>
<body>

    <div class="wrapper">

        <span class="text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.</span>

        <p class="info"></p>

    </div>

    <script>

        function setElementInfo() {
            var element = document.querySelector('.text');
            var info    = document.querySelector('.info');
            var message = navigator.userAgent + '<br>' + 'element offsetWidth = ' + element.offsetWidth;
            info.innerHTML = message;
        }

        // setElementInfo();
        window.addEventListener('load', setElementInfo);

    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

css/styles.css

```
*,
*:before,
*:after {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
       -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
            box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {

    /* system font */
    font-family: Arial;

    /* custom font */
    /*font-family: "Open Sans", sans-serif;*/
}

.wrapper {
    background-color: #5ad;
}

.text {
    display: inline-block;
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #da5;
}
```

css/animate.css

```
.wrapper {
    width: 960px;
    margin: 30px auto;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.text {

    padding-left: 100%;
    white-space: nowrap;

    -webkit-animation: animate 7s linear 0ms infinite;
            animation: animate 7s linear 0ms infinite;
}

.text:hover {
    -webkit-animation-play-state: paused;
            animation-play-state: paused;
}

@-webkit-keyframes animate {
    0% {
        -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
                transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    }
    100% {
        -webkit-transform: translate3d(-100%, 0, 0);
                transform: translate3d(-100%, 0, 0);
    }
}

@keyframes animate {
    0% {
        -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
                transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    }
    100% {
        -webkit-transform: translate3d(-100%, 0, 0);
                transform: translate3d(-100%, 0, 0);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't think that there should be anything wrong with how this animation works; because the translate values are %'s, everything will be relative.

`transform: translate3d(-100%, 0, 0);`

Check out this codepen in both Chrome and Safari, the result looks the same: https://codepen.io/segheysens/pen/gxWXaZ

Comment: Thanks for answering so fast. I have tried it on codepen.io (your link) and i changed the text to "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Mollitia fugiat ratione quos illum maiores doloremque corporis laborum consequatur necessitatibus alias. Repudiandae recusandae et quasi id, quas voluptate ad pariatur nesciunt."

Comment: Could you describe what is wrong when you are viewing the result? I tried updating the text to what you wrote above, and it looks the same to me in both browsers.

Comment: Forget for now the animation :-).

It's the element width (offsetWidth) i'm wondering. You can see the differences in the yellow blocks in my question (chrome and firefox both show 416 Pixel offsetWidth, safari shows 1047 Pixel).

safari's inspector in contrast show the "right" value of 416 Pixel (416,47 to be exact).

You can see the effect, when you reload the page in safari quickly several times. For a short moment you see that the element will be too wide based of the background-color of the element.